# Sorting of works in multiple reference lists

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa7

I'm writing my thesis, and I need to present the references used during the writing in separate lists according to the type of material used.

For that, I found very useful the examples used here: https://texblog.org/2012/10/22/multiple-bibliographies-with-biblatex/.

I created three different .bib files, as I'm using a lot of materials, so it's easier for my own organization: (i) `bibliography.bib`, (ii) `norms.bib`, and (iii) `cases.bib`.

On the MWE below, I use only two files, as it's enough to demonstrate the problem.

The first list of references, encompassing bibliographical material, is correctly sorted in alphabetical order. However, the following lists (USA legislation and EU legislation) are sorted randomly. I could not understand how the works are being sorted, and neither find a way to sort it alphabetically too.

The MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, english]{abntex2}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,language=english]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\addbibresource{norms.bib}
\addbibresource{cases.bib}

\begin{document}

Some references\footfullcite{European_Commission,European_Commission_2005,EC_DGMHA_2021,IFRC_2021,Schengen_Agreement}

EU legislation\footfullcite{CEU_2008,CEU_2008a,CEU_2009,EP_CEU_2018,EP_CEU_2018a,Schengen_1985,Schengen_1990}

USA legislation\footfullcite{SensenbrennerJr_2002,Cantwell_2021,DelBene_2021,Eshoo_2021}

\printbibliography[title={References},notkeyword=us_norm,notkeyword=eu_norm,notkeyword=norm,notkeyword=cases]
\printbibliography[title={Referenced U.S.A. Legislation},keyword=us_norm]
\printbibliography[title={Referenced E.U. Legislation},keyword=eu_norm]

\end{document}
```

Here are the entries from the .bib files:
(i) `bibliography.bib`

```
@misc{European_Commission,
title       =   {Schengen Area},
url         =   {https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/schengen-area_en}, 
journal     =   {Migration and Home Affairs},
author      =   {{European Commission}},
language    =   {en}
}
@misc{European_Commission_2005,
title       =   {{Communication from the Commission to the Council and the European Parliament - The Hague Programme: Ten priorities for the next five years The Partnership for European renewal in the field of Freedom, Security and Justice COM/2005/0184 final}}, 
url         =   {https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:52005DC0184},
author      =   {{European Commission}},
year        =   {2005}, 
month       =   {05},
language    =   {en}
}
@misc{EC_DGMHA_2021,
title       =   {{Proposal for a REGULATION OF THE EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT AND OF THE COUNCIL on automated data exchange for police cooperation (“Pr\"{u}m II”), amending Council Decisions 2008/615/JHA and 2008/616/JHA and Regulations (EU) 2018/1726, 2019/817 and 2019/818 of the European Parliament and of the Council COM/2021/784 final}}, 
url         =   {https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=COM:2021:784:FIN},
author      =   {{European Commission and Directorate-General for Migration and Home Affairs}},
year        =   {2021},
month       =   {12},
language    =   {en}
}
@misc{IFRC_2021,
address     =   {Geneva, Switzerland},
title       =   {{Digital Identity: Enabling Dignified Access to Humaniratian Services in Migration}}, 
url         =   {https://preparecenter.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Digital-Identity-Enabling-dignified-access-to-humanitarian-services-in-Migration-Final.pdf},
DOI         =   {10.1163/2210-7975_HRD-9813-2015012},
publisher   =   {International Federation of Red Cross and Red Crescent Societies (FIRC)},
author      =   {{International Federation of Red Cross and Red Crescent Societies}},
year        =   {2021}, 
month       =   {06},
pages       =   {54},
language    =   {en}
}
@misc{Schengen_Agreement,
title       =   {Schengen Agreement},
url         =   {https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-agreement/},
journal     =   {SchengenVisaInfo.com},
language    =   {en}
}
```

And the entries from the `norms.bib`

```
@legislation{CEU_2008,
keywords    =   {eu_norm},
title       =   {{Council Decision 2008/615/JHA of 23 June 2008 on the stepping up of cross-border cooperation, particularly in combating terrorism and cross-border crime}},
url         =   {http://data.europa.eu/eli/dec/2008/615/oj},
author      =   {{Council of the European Union}},
journal     =   {OJ},
volume      =   {L 210},
year        =   {2008},
month       =   {08}, 
pages       =   {1–11},
language    =   {en}
}
@legislation{CEU_2008a,
keywords    =   {eu_norm},
title       =   {{Council Decision 2008/616/JHA of 23 June 2008 on the implementation of Decision 2008/615/JHA on the stepping up of cross-border cooperation, particularly in combating terrorism and cross-border crime}}, 
url         =   {http://data.europa.eu/eli/dec/2008/616/oj},
author      =   {{Council of the European Union}},
journal     =   {OJ},
volume      =   {L 210},
year        =   {2008},
month       =   {08}, 
pages       =   {12–72},
language    =   {en}
}
@legislation{CEU_2009,
keywords    =   {eu_norm},
title       =   {{Council Framework Decision 2009/905/JHA of 30 November 2009 on Accreditation of forensic service providers carrying out laboratory activities}},
url         =   {http://data.europa.eu/eli/dec_framw/2009/905/oj},
author      =   {{Council of the European Union}},
journal     =   {OJ},
volume      =   {L 322},
year        =   {2009},
month       =   {12},
pages       =   {14–16},
language    =   {en}
}
@legislation{EP_CEU_2018,
keywords    =   {eu_norm},
title       =   {{Regulation (EU) 2018/1861 of the European Parliament and of the Council of 28 November 2018 on the establishment, operation and use of the Schengen Information System (SIS) in the field of border checks, and amending the Convention implementing the Schengen Agreement, and amending and repealing Regulation (EC) No 1987/2006}}, 
url         =   {http://data.europa.eu/eli/reg/2018/1861/oj},
author      =   {{European Parliament and Council of the European Union}},
journal     =   {OJ},
volume      =   {L 312},
year        =   {2018},
month       =   {12},
pages       =   {14–55},
language    =   {en}
}
@legislation{EP_CEU_2018a,
keywords    =   {eu_norm},
title       =   {{Regulation (EU) 2018/1862 of the European Parliament and of the Council of 28 November 2018 on the establishment, operation and use of the Schengen Information System (SIS) in the field of police cooperation and judicial cooperation in criminal matters, amending and repealing Council Decision 2007/533/JHA, and repealing Regulation (EC) No 1986/2006 of the European Parliament and of the Council and Commission Decision 2010/261/EU}}, 
url         =   {http://data.europa.eu/eli/reg/2018/1862/oj},
author      =   {{European Parliament and Council of the European Union}},
journal     =   {OJ},
volume      =   {L 312},
year        =   {2018},
month       =   {12},
pages       =   {56–106},
language    =   {en}
}
@legislation{Schengen_1985,
keywords    =   {eu_norm},
title       =   {{The Schengen acquis - Agreement between the Governments of the States of the Benelux Economic Union, the Federal Republic of Germany and the French Republic on the gradual abolition of checks at their common borders}}, 
url         =   {http://data.europa.eu/eli/agree_internation/2000/922(1)/oj},
author      =   {{Belgium, France, Germany, Luxembourg, Netherlands}},
journal     =   {OJ},
volume      =   {L 239},
year        =   {1985},
month       =   {06},
pages       =   {13–18},
language    =   {en}
}
@legislation{Schengen_1990,
keywords    =   {eu_norm},
title       =   {{The Schengen acquis - Convention implementing the Schengen Agreement of 14 June 1985 between the Governments of the States of the Benelux Economic Union, the Federal Republic of Germany and the French Republic on the gradual abolition of checks at their common borders}},
url         =   {https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:42000A0922(02)},
author      =   {{Belgium, France, Germany, Luxembourg, Netherlands}},
journal     =   {OJ},
volume      =   {L 239},
year        =   {1990},
month       =   {06},
pages       =   {19–62}, 
language    =   {en}
}
@legislation{Cantwell_2021,
keywords    =   {us_norm},
location    =   {S. 3195, 117th Congress (2021-2022)},
title       =   {Consumer Online Privacy Rights Act},
url         =   {https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/senate-bill/3195?s=4&r=8634},
author      =   {Cantwell, Maria},
year        =   {2021},
month       =   {11}
}
@legislation{DelBene_2021,
keywords    =   {us_norm},
location    =   {H.R. 1816, 117th Congress (2021-2022)},
title       =   {Information Transparency \& Personal Data Control Act},
url         =   {https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/1816?s=3&r=5039},
author      =   {DelBene, Suzan K.},
year        =   {2021},
month       =   {03}
}
@legislation{Eshoo_2021,
keywords    =   {us_norm},
location    =   {H.R. 6027, 117th Congress (2021-2022)},
title       =   {Online Privacy Act},
tittleaddon =   {of 2021},
url         =   {https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/6027?s=7&r=828},
author      =   {Eshoo, Anna G.},
year        =   {2021},
month       =   {11},
}
@legislation{SensenbrennerJr_2002,
keywords    =   {us_norm},
location    =   {107th Congress (2001-2002)},
title       =   {{Enhanced Border Security and Visa Entry Reform Act}},
tittleaddon =   {of 2002},
url         =   {https://www.congress.gov/bill/107th-congress/house-bill/3525},
number      =   {H.R.3525},
author      =   {Sensenbrenner, Jr., Frank James},
year        =   {2002},
language    =   {en}
}
```

It produces the following results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The references in the .bib files are following the structure presented here: https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/master/bibtex/bib/biblatex-apa-test-references.bib#L2563

I have already tried to use the `sorting=nty` option of `biblatex`, but it didn't work.

Would someone have any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Please share a few of the relevant `.bib` entries with us so that we can test our solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@legislation` entries in the question have `author` fields that are not shown in the output. But because `biblatex-apa` sorts by name, the `author` fields are used for sorting.

Delete the `author` fields to get a much more expected output. If you cannot delete these fields at the source, use a sourcemap.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, english]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,language=english]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      \pertype{legislation}
      \step[fieldset=author, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{European_Commission,
title       =   {Schengen Area},
url         =   {https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/schengen-area_en}, 
journal     =   {Migration and Home Affairs},
author      =   {{European Commission}},
language    =   {en}
}
@misc{European_Commission_2005,
title       =   {{Communication from the Commission to the Council and the European Parliament - The Hague Programme: Ten priorities for the next five years The Partnership for European renewal in the field of Freedom, Security and Justice COM/2005/0184 final}}, 
url         =   {https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:52005DC0184},
author      =   {{European Commission}},
year        =   {2005}, 
month       =   {05},
language    =   {en}
}
@misc{EC_DGMHA_2021,
title       =   {{Proposal for a REGULATION OF THE EUROPEAN PARLIAMENT AND OF THE COUNCIL on automated data exchange for police cooperation (“Pr\"{u}m II”), amending Council Decisions 2008/615/JHA and 2008/616/JHA and Regulations (EU) 2018/1726, 2019/817 and 2019/818 of the European Parliament and of the Council COM/2021/784 final}}, 
url         =   {https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=COM:2021:784:FIN},
author      =   {{European Commission and Directorate-General for Migration and Home Affairs}},
year        =   {2021},
month       =   {12},
language    =   {en}
}
@misc{IFRC_2021,
address     =   {Geneva, Switzerland},
title       =   {{Digital Identity: Enabling Dignified Access to Humaniratian Services in Migration}}, 
url         =   {https://preparecenter.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Digital-Identity-Enabling-dignified-access-to-humanitarian-services-in-Migration-Final.pdf},
DOI         =   {10.1163/2210-7975_HRD-9813-2015012},
publisher   =   {International Federation of Red Cross and Red Crescent Societies (FIRC)},
author      =   {{International Federation of Red Cross and Red Crescent Societies}},
year        =   {2021}, 
month       =   {06},
pages       =   {54},
language    =   {en}
}
@misc{Schengen_Agreement,
title       =   {Schengen Agreement},
url         =   {https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-agreement/},
journal     =   {SchengenVisaInfo.com},
language    =   {en}
}
@legislation{CEU_2008,
keywords    =   {eu_norm},
title       =   {{Council Decision 2008/615/JHA of 23 June 2008 on the stepping up of cross-border cooperation, particularly in combating terrorism and cross-border crime}},
url         =   {http://data.europa.eu/eli/dec/2008/615/oj},
author      =   {{Council of the European Union}},
journal     =   {OJ},
volume      =   {L 210},
year        =   {2008},
month       =   {08}, 
pages       =   {1–11},
language    =   {en}
}
@legislation{CEU_2008a,
keywords    =   {eu_norm},
title       =   {{Council Decision 2008/616/JHA of 23 June 2008 on the implementation of Decision 2008/615/JHA on the stepping up of cross-border cooperation, particularly in combating terrorism and cross-border crime}}, 
url         =   {http://data.europa.eu/eli/dec/2008/616/oj},
author      =   {{Council of the European Union}},
journal     =   {OJ},
volume      =   {L 210},
year        =   {2008},
month       =   {08}, 
pages       =   {12–72},
language    =   {en}
}
@legislation{CEU_2009,
keywords    =   {eu_norm},
title       =   {{Council Framework Decision 2009/905/JHA of 30 November 2009 on Accreditation of forensic service providers carrying out laboratory activities}},
url         =   {http://data.europa.eu/eli/dec_framw/2009/905/oj},
author      =   {{Council of the European Union}},
journal     =   {OJ},
volume      =   {L 322},
year        =   {2009},
month       =   {12},
pages       =   {14–16},
language    =   {en}
}
@legislation{EP_CEU_2018,
keywords    =   {eu_norm},
title       =   {{Regulation (EU) 2018/1861 of the European Parliament and of the Council of 28 November 2018 on the establishment, operation and use of the Schengen Information System (SIS) in the field of border checks, and amending the Convention implementing the Schengen Agreement, and amending and repealing Regulation (EC) No 1987/2006}}, 
url         =   {http://data.europa.eu/eli/reg/2018/1861/oj},
author      =   {{European Parliament and Council of the European Union}},
journal     =   {OJ},
volume      =   {L 312},
year        =   {2018},
month       =   {12},
pages       =   {14–55},
language    =   {en}
}
@legislation{EP_CEU_2018a,
keywords    =   {eu_norm},
title       =   {{Regulation (EU) 2018/1862 of the European Parliament and of the Council of 28 November 2018 on the establishment, operation and use of the Schengen Information System (SIS) in the field of police cooperation and judicial cooperation in criminal matters, amending and repealing Council Decision 2007/533/JHA, and repealing Regulation (EC) No 1986/2006 of the European Parliament and of the Council and Commission Decision 2010/261/EU}}, 
url         =   {http://data.europa.eu/eli/reg/2018/1862/oj},
author      =   {{European Parliament and Council of the European Union}},
journal     =   {OJ},
volume      =   {L 312},
year        =   {2018},
month       =   {12},
pages       =   {56–106},
language    =   {en}
}
@legislation{Schengen_1985,
keywords    =   {eu_norm},
title       =   {{The Schengen acquis - Agreement between the Governments of the States of the Benelux Economic Union, the Federal Republic of Germany and the French Republic on the gradual abolition of checks at their common borders}}, 
url         =   {http://data.europa.eu/eli/agree_internation/2000/922(1)/oj},
author      =   {{Belgium, France, Germany, Luxembourg, Netherlands}},
journal     =   {OJ},
volume      =   {L 239},
year        =   {1985},
month       =   {06},
pages       =   {13–18},
language    =   {en}
}
@legislation{Schengen_1990,
keywords    =   {eu_norm},
title       =   {{The Schengen acquis - Convention implementing the Schengen Agreement of 14 June 1985 between the Governments of the States of the Benelux Economic Union, the Federal Republic of Germany and the French Republic on the gradual abolition of checks at their common borders}},
url         =   {https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:42000A0922(02)},
author      =   {{Belgium, France, Germany, Luxembourg, Netherlands}},
journal     =   {OJ},
volume      =   {L 239},
year        =   {1990},
month       =   {06},
pages       =   {19–62}, 
language    =   {en}
}
@legislation{Cantwell_2021,
keywords    =   {us_norm},
location    =   {S. 3195, 117th Congress (2021-2022)},
title       =   {Consumer Online Privacy Rights Act},
url         =   {https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/senate-bill/3195?s=4&r=8634},
author      =   {Cantwell, Maria},
year        =   {2021},
month       =   {11}
}
@legislation{DelBene_2021,
keywords    =   {us_norm},
location    =   {H.R. 1816, 117th Congress (2021-2022)},
title       =   {Information Transparency \& Personal Data Control Act},
url         =   {https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/1816?s=3&r=5039},
author      =   {DelBene, Suzan K.},
year        =   {2021},
month       =   {03}
}
@legislation{Eshoo_2021,
keywords    =   {us_norm},
location    =   {H.R. 6027, 117th Congress (2021-2022)},
title       =   {Online Privacy Act},
tittleaddon =   {of 2021},
url         =   {https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/6027?s=7&r=828},
author      =   {Eshoo, Anna G.},
year        =   {2021},
month       =   {11},
}
@legislation{SensenbrennerJr_2002,
keywords    =   {us_norm},
location    =   {107th Congress (2001-2002)},
title       =   {{Enhanced Border Security and Visa Entry Reform Act}},
tittleaddon =   {of 2002},
url         =   {https://www.congress.gov/bill/107th-congress/house-bill/3525},
number      =   {H.R.3525},
author      =   {Sensenbrenner, Jr., Frank James},
year        =   {2002},
language    =   {en}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some references\footfullcite{European_Commission,European_Commission_2005,EC_DGMHA_2021,IFRC_2021,Schengen_Agreement}

EU legislation\footfullcite{CEU_2008,CEU_2008a,CEU_2009,EP_CEU_2018,EP_CEU_2018a,Schengen_1985,Schengen_1990}

USA legislation\footfullcite{SensenbrennerJr_2002,Cantwell_2021,DelBene_2021,Eshoo_2021}

\printbibliography[title={References},notkeyword=us_norm,notkeyword=eu_norm,notkeyword=norm,notkeyword=cases]
\printbibliography[title={Referenced U.S.A. Legislation},keyword=us_norm]
\printbibliography[title={Referenced E.U. Legislation},keyword=eu_norm]

\end{document}
```

[image: Correctly sorted EU legislation list]

Comment: Thank you @moewe. It worked just perfectly.